# Запятая при существительных

Tags: общие-вопросы

Флейта-пикколо или малая флейта. Почему перед или нет запятой, ведь это разные названия одного предмета. Мне не понятно, объясните, как правильно.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в определении запятая нужна (Это флейта-пикколо, или /= иначе, она же, в переводе с итальянского и пр./ малая флейта). Другое дело, когда разные наименования в предложении объединены общим понятием, и запятой не требуется. Например:

Этот инструмент называют флейтой-пикколо или малой флейтой.

(называют "так или иначе"; аналогичная фраза без запятой - в википедии)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере союз "или" объединяет однородные члены предложения, поэтому запятая не нужна. Запятая ставится в зависимости от контекста в предложении.
Следует различать пояснительный союз ***или*** (перед которым запятая ставится) и разделительный союз ***или*** ***(перед которым запятая не ставится, если союз не повторяется).*** Ср.: ***Флексия, или окончание, бывает только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи (здесь ''или" имеет значение "то есть", повторить союз нельзя).***  -  ***Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется флексией или окончанием (здесь ''или" имеет разделительное значение, союз может быть повторен)***.

> См.: Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
>
> СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ

Comment: И все равно мне не понятно. Флексия - это второе название окончания, поэтому в последнем Вашем предложении:  Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется флексией или окончанием - перед или,  я считаю, нужна запятая. Флексия и окончание не являются однородными. Возьмем,  например, предложение: Дядя Сергей Николаевич начал меня учить чистописанию, или каллиграфии.